# Informix Date Query GROUP BY Month

Tags: sql, date, datetime, group-by, informix

How do I select records using GROUP BY on Informix Date datatype on month? Like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM db_table
WHERE my_date.year = 2012
GROUP BY my_date.month
```

Can I use like this?

```
GROUP BY MONTH(my_date)
```

I don't know if this function exists in Informix or not. Currently I cannot access the server to verify it.

By the way I'm using the a little bit old version, the version 10. In the document of the version, It describes as following of Time functions:

```
You can use the time functions DAY, MDY, MONTH, WEEKDAY, and YEAR in either the projection clause or the WHERE clause of a query.
```

It seems that I cannot use MONTH function on GROUP BY. Is there any solution?

Comment: i think GROUP BY MONTH(my_date) is correct  and also you can try on http://sqlfiddle.com/ for testing your any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informix documention says that there are [`MONTH()` and `YEAR()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls1108.htm) functions

Therefore your query should work for you

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM db_table
 WHERE YEAR(my_date) = 2012
 GROUP BY MONTH(my_date)
```

Comment: Can you perform this query? I used the query and Informix said there's syntax error.

Comment: @MarcusThornton is correct - this creates a syntax error. Answer by Rod is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been investigating this problem. Informix has some strange limitations, one is that you can't directly use date related functions in a GROUP BY statement. You need to 'GROUP BY' one of the output columns in your select statement.

The following should solve the problem:

```
SELECT MONTH(my_date), COUNT(*)
 FROM db_table
 WHERE YEAR(my_date) = '2012'
 GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score -1):

use like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM db_table
 WHERE YEAR(my_date) = '2012'
 GROUP BY MONTH(my_date)
```